# jQuery - how to be able to set a milliseconds using the Intimidatetime?

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is to use the [Intimidatetime](https://github.com/trentrichardson/Intimidatetime), and be able to also choose the milliseconds.

In order to do so I used the next code -

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Intimidatetime.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {


            $('#ex_basic_1').intimidatetime({
                //format: 'u',
                previewFormat: 'HH:mm:ss:l',
            })

        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="ex_basic_1" value="" class="inputFull" />


</body>
</html>
```

But the thing is that I'm not getting the select input for the milliseconds, I'm only getting the other select options (year,month,day,hour,minute and second).

Does anyone knows how may i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "format" like this:

```
    $('#ex_basic_1').intimidatetime({
        previewFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:l',
        format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:l"
    })
```